# How to train custom NER in Spacy with single words data set?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am trying to train a custom ner in Spacy with the new entity 'ANIMAL'. But I have a data set with single words as:

```
TRAIN_DATA = [("Whale_ Blue", {"entities": [(0,11,LABEL)]}), ("Shark_ whale", {"entities": [(0,12,LABEL)]}), ("Elephant_ African", {"entities": [(0,17,LABEL)]}), ("Elephant_ Indian", {"entities": [(0,16,LABEL)]}), ("Giraffe_ male", {"entities": [(0,13,LABEL)]}), ("Mule", {"entities": [(0,4,LABEL)]}), ("Camel", {"entities": [(0,5,LABEL)]}), ("Horse", {"entities": [(0,5,LABEL)]}), ("Cow", {"entities": [(0,3,LABEL)]}), ("Dolphin_ Bottlenose", {"entities": [(0,19,LABEL)]}), ("Donkey", {"entities": [(0,6,LABEL)]}), ("Tapir", {"entities": [(0,5,LABEL)]}), ("Shark_ Hammerhead", {"entities": [(0,17,LABEL)]}), ("Seal_ fur", {"entities": [(0,9,LABEL)]}), ("Manatee", {"entities": [(0,7,LABEL)]}), ("Bear_ Grizzly", {"entities": [(0,13,LABEL)]}), ("Alligator_ American", {"entities": [(0,19,LABEL)]}), ("Sturgeon_ Atlantic", {"entities": [(0,18,LABEL)]}), ("Lion", {"entities": [(0,4,LABEL)]}), ("Bear_ American Black", {"entities": [(0,20,LABEL)]}), ("Ostrich", {"entities": [(0,7,LABEL)]}), ("Crocodile_ Saltwater", {"entities": [(0,20,LABEL)]}), ("Pig", {"entities": [(0,3,LABEL)]}), ("Sheep", {"entities": [(0,5,LABEL)]}), ("Dog_ Saint Bernard", {"entities": [(0,18,LABEL)]}), ("Human", {"entities": [(0,5,LABEL)]}), ("Deer_ white-tailed", {"entities": [(0,18,LABEL)]}), ("Tuna", {"entities": [(0,4,LABEL)]}), ("Salamander_ Japanese", {"entities": [(0,20,LABEL)]}), ("Carp", {"entities": [(0,4,LABEL)]}), ("Dog_ Foxhound", {"entities": [(0,13,LABEL)]}), ("Goat_ Milch", {"entities": [(0,11,LABEL)]}), ("Sting Ray", {"entities": [(0,9,LABEL)]}), ("Dog_ Pointer", {"entities": [(0,12,LABEL)]}), ("Kangaroo_ Red", {"entities": [(0,13,LABEL)]}), ("Cod_ Atlantic", {"entities": [(0,13,LABEL)]}), ("Dog_ Collie", {"entities": [(0,11,LABEL)]}), ("Pike_ Northern", {"entities": [(0,14,LABEL)]}), ("Trout_ brown", {"entities": [(0,12,LABEL)]}), ("Dog_ Basset Hound", {"entities": [(0,17,LABEL)]}), ("Turkey", {"entities": [(0,6,LABEL)]}), ("Porcupine", {"entities": [(0,9,LABEL)]}), ("Trout_ Rainbow", {"entities": [(0,14,LABEL)]}), ("Gar_ longnose", {"entities": [(0,13,LABEL)]}), ("Beaver", {"entities": [(0,6,LABEL)]}), ("Dog_ Irish Terrier", {"entities": [(0,18,LABEL)]}), ("Dog_ Beagle", {"entities": [(0,11,LABEL)]}), ("Bass_ Large Mouth Black", {"entities": [(0,23,LABEL)]}), ("Dog_ Whippet", {"entities": [(0,12,LABEL)]}), ("Dog_ Boston Terrier", {"entities": [(0,19,LABEL)]}), ("Nutria", {"entities": [(0,6,LABEL)]}), ("Dog_ Fox Terrier", {"entities": [(0,16,LABEL)]}), ("Armadillo_ Nine-banded", {"entities": [(0,22,LABEL)]}), ("Fox_ Arctic", {"entities": [(0,11,LABEL)]}), ("Woodchuck (Groundhog)", {"entities": [(0,21,LABEL)]}), ("Rabbit_ Domestic", {"entities": [(0,16,LABEL)]}), ("Chicken", {"entities": [(0,7,LABEL)]}), ("Dog_ Pekingese", {"entities": [(0,14,LABEL)]}), ("Haddock", {"entities": [(0,7,LABEL)]}), ("Cat_ domestic", {"entities": [(0,13,LABEL)]}), ("Salmon_ Chum", {"entities": [(0,12,LABEL)]}), ("Vulture_ Turkey", {"entities": [(0,15,LABEL)]}), ("Opossum_ Large American", {"entities": [(0,23,LABEL)]}), ("Flounder_ Winter", {"entities": [(0,16,LABEL)]}), ("Pheasant_ Ringnecked", {"entities": [(0,20,LABEL)]}), ("Perch", {"entities": [(0,5,LABEL)]}), ("Duck_ Mallard", {"entities": [(0,13,LABEL)]}), ("Mackerel_ Spanish", {"entities": [(0,17,LABEL)]}), ("Platypus_ Duck-billed", {"entities": [(0,21,LABEL)]}), ("Sea lamprey", {"entities": [(0,11,LABEL)]}), ("Bullhead_ Brown", {"entities": [(0,15,LABEL)]}), ("Mink_ American", {"entities": [(0,14,LABEL)]}), ("Falcon_ Peregrin", {"entities": [(0,16,LABEL)]}), ("Goshawk", {"entities": [(0,7,LABEL)]}), ("Bat_ Flying fox", {"entities": [(0,15,LABEL)]}), ("Duck_ Wood", {"entities": [(0,10,LABEL)]}), ("Buzzard", {"entities": [(0,7,LABEL)]}), ("Bass_ Rock", {"entities": [(0,10,LABEL)]}), ("Squirrel_ Gray", {"entities": [(0,14,LABEL)]}), ("Guinea Pig", {"entities": [(0,10,LABEL)]}), ("Rat_ Norway", {"entities": [(0,11,LABEL)]}), ("Gull_ Herring", {"entities": [(0,13,LABEL)]}), ("Crow_ Hooded", {"entities": [(0,12,LABEL)]}), ("Rook", {"entities": [(0,4,LABEL)]}), ("Pumpkinseed", {"entities": [(0,11,LABEL)]}), ("Pigeon", {"entities": [(0,6,LABEL)]}), ("Guinea fowl", {"entities": [(0,11,LABEL)]}), ("Quail_ Bobwhite", {"entities": [(0,15,LABEL)]}), ("Magpie_ Black-billed", {"entities": [(0,20,LABEL)]}), ("European Jackdaw", {"entities": [(0,16,LABEL)]}), ("Hamster", {"entities": [(0,7,LABEL)]}), ("Kestrel_ lesser", {"entities": [(0,15,LABEL)]}), ("Hawk_ Night", {"entities": [(0,11,LABEL)]}), ("Chipmunk_ Eastern", {"entities": [(0,17,LABEL)]}), ("Bat_ little brown", {"entities": [(0,17,LABEL)]}), ("Starling_ Common", {"entities": [(0,16,LABEL)]}), ("Frog_ leopard", {"entities": [(0,13,LABEL)]}), ("Weasel_ least", {"entities": [(0,13,LABEL)]}), ("Mouse_ White-footed", {"entities": [(0,19,LABEL)]}), ("Mouse_ House", {"entities": [(0,12,LABEL)]}), ("Canary", {"entities": [(0,6,LABEL)]}), ("Hummingbird", {"entities": [(0,11,LABEL)]}), ("Hummingbird_ Cuban bee", {"entities": [(0,22,LABEL)]}), ("Shrew_ Musked", {"entities": [(0,13,LABEL)]}), ("Shrew_ dwarf", {"entities": [(0,12,LABEL)]}), ("Goby_ Philippine", {"entities": [(0,16,LABEL)]}), ("Goldfish", {"entities": [(0,8,LABEL)]}), ("Toad_ American", {"entities": [(0,14,LABEL)]}), ("Frog_ Bull", {"entities": [(0,10,LABEL)]}), ("Eel_ American", {"entities": [(0,13,LABEL)]}), ("Penguin_ Adelie", {"entities": [(0,15,LABEL)]}), ("Robin", {"entities": [(0,5,LABEL)]}), ("Kiwi", {"entities": [(0,4,LABEL)]}), ("Fighting Fish_ Siamese", {"entities": [(0,22,LABEL)]}), ("Skate", {"entities": [(0,5,LABEL)]}), ("Quail_ Japanese/European", {"entities": [(0,24,LABEL)]}), ("Gila Monster", {"entities": [(0,12,LABEL)]}), ("Chameleon", {"entities": [(0,9,LABEL)]}), ("Cobra_ Indian", {"entities": [(0,13,LABEL)]}), ("Boa Constrictor", {"entities": [(0,15,LABEL)]}), ("Guppy", {"entities": [(0,5,LABEL)]}), ("Salamander_ Tiger", {"entities": [(0,17,LABEL)]}), ("Swordtail_ Mexican", {"entities": [(0,18,LABEL)]}), ("Stickleback_ three spine", {"entities": [(0,24,LABEL)]}), ("Sea horse", {"entities": [(0,9,LABEL)]}), ("Hellbender", {"entities": [(0,10,LABEL)]}), ("Herring_ Atlantic", {"entities": [(0,17,LABEL)]}), ("Chameleon_ Madagascar", {"entities": [(0,21,LABEL)]}), ("Frog_ Cuban", {"entities": [(0,11,LABEL)]}), ]
```

I have used the python script mention here https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_new_entity_type.py

After training the model, I am getting the incorrect result as Spacy also detects other words 'ANIMAL'.

Can anyone guide me, how to do this in the right way? 
Spacy ver: 2.1.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spacy NER model training includes the extraction of other "implicit" features, such as **POS** and **surrounding words**.

When you attempt to train on single words, it is unable to get generalized enought features to detect those entities.

Take, for instance, this example extracted from [Spacy's own training tutorial](https://spacy.io/usage/training/):

```
train_data = [
    ("Uber blew through $1 million a week", [(0, 4, 'ORG')]),
    ("Android Pay expands to Canada", [(0, 11, 'PRODUCT'), (23, 30, 'GPE')]),
    ("Spotify steps up Asia expansion", [(0, 8, "ORG"), (17, 21, "LOC")]),
    ("Google Maps launches location sharing", [(0, 11, "PRODUCT")]),
    ("Google rebrands its business apps", [(0, 6, "ORG")]),
    ("look what i found on google! ", [(21, 27, "PRODUCT")])]
```

How could the NER Model correctly guess what kind of Entity the word "Google" refers in that context if not by the surroundings? The same goes for your words. **NER is not a "Regex"-like function, but rather a machine learning model.**

Comment: Then what can I do with my use case? Any possible solution?

Comment: You need several samples for each label representative. You have to gather a corpus of many sentences containing animals (a text dataset) and label them. One tool that may help you is Doccano -> https://github.com/chakki-works/doccano.